# Force generating aspx.designer.cs files in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin IDE of Mac for ASP.NET (C#) Project. How to force Xamarin to Generate/Re-generate aspx.designer.cs files ? That's in plain text !

Even with simple pages the designer files are not synchronized with the last changes in aspx file. Except that files generated natively with Xamarin.

I do all the things you can imagine (Cleaning, Rebuilding , Building). The HTML syntax inside is correct hundred percent.

Notice , I'm not talking about one page , but about the entire project.

Please help !

Comment: This might just be another bug in Xamarin. It has a lot of those. If this is the case and you pay for them enough, they might help you with this. Otherwise just wait and see if they fix it, or use something else.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I use the normal version, this is critical (STUPID) thing which stopping my progress !

Comment: The .aspx.designer.cs file is generated when you save the corresponding .aspx file in Xamarin Studio. If that is not working, then I would look in the IDE log file (Help - Open Log Directory) to see if an exception is being thrown.

Comment: @MattWard thanks , that was helpfull